# PreparedStatement select com like em Java Swing

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Quero executar a seguinte função para criar um filtro em minha aplicação.

public void filter(String filter) {

```
    String sql = "SELECT processador from computador where processador like '%?%'";

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;

    try {
        conn = Conexao.connectionToMySQL();
        pstm = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstm.setString(1, filter);
        pstm.execute();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (pstm != null) {
                pstm.close();
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Porém recebo esse erro na hora de executar o botão criado no javaSwing:

java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

gostaria de saber onde está meu erro nessa função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando é utilizado o método `setString` do `PreparedStatment`, não se faz necessário o uso de aspas simples, pois método se encarrega de fazer isso.  Dessa forma, deve deixando apenas o `?` já é o suficiente.
E, no seu caso específico, o seu `setString`, deve ser colocado dessa forma:

```
pstm.setString(1, "%" + filter + "%");
```

Sendo assim, também deve ser removido ambos `%`  da String `sql` de forma de que fique assim:

```
String sql = "SELECT processador FROM computador WHERE processador LIKE ?";
```

Veja mais em: [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)